# $.each in jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function like

```
Function getCities(abbr) {
         $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "Main/aaa",
                     data1: "{}",
                     success: function (response) {

                     }
 });
```

As a response I get some object array. Format looks like

```
[{id: 1, decr: "some string"},
 {id: 3, decr: "some string2"}]
```

etc..(each member of the array has values id and desc)

Problem for me is to parse this response and get some list with id and desc values. I tried to write something like

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
   items += "<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>";
});
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Is there a problem with each? I checked and I got a response, I just need to find a way to parse it.

Comment: where did you place the each loop

Comment: what mean by doesnt work? any error in console? if it is json, you need to json.parse it before you can loop it

Comment: In success: function (response){ each loop}
@SeOng11 its not display values.

Comment: The response you get should be `[0]{id:1, decr:"some string"}` etc.

Comment: tip1: open console and see if you getting some error, tip2: add dataType: 'json'

Comment: try logging in console from `$.each`

Comment: firstly try this: console.log( key + ": " + value); if does not work post your JSON result completely

Comment: @JananiM Is this JSON? If it *is* JSON, set `dataType:'json'` in your `$.ajax()` function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Then jQuery tries to convert it into a readable `object`.

Comment: @DOCASAREL I did n't say the above comment as json.. Asked to post the JSON

Comment: @Maja check this http://jsfiddle.net/8r2kouu8/ it works perfectly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is JSON type. After reviewing your each() function, I modified your each function as below.

Try this:

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {
   items += "<option value='" + key + "'>" +value.id+" "+value.decr+ "</option>";
});
```

Comment: JSON-type? Where do you get that from? `'{"bar":"new property","baz":3}'` that's JSON. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#Converting_objects_into_JSON.

Comment: Yes, in your question the format is as you mentioned. Try it, I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Although not your issue, the act of transforming each value in a list to some other value is called in functional languages as mapping. And jQuery [does support it](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var options = $.map(response, function(item){
    return $('<option />', { value: item.id, text: item.desc }) 
});
```

This will return a array of `option` elements. Learning how to write in a more functional style when programming in jQuery pays off in the long run.